# Gmail REST API: send reply message with attachments uploadType=media

Tags: gmail-api, mime-message

I really need your help!
I want to send a reply message with the Gmail REST API. Using the standard url: 
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send, everything works fine. By sending the raw data of the message and the thread id, the new message is attached to the same thread.

Now as I want our customers to be able to upload bigger attachments i use the upload url: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=media.

I send the request with Content-Type set to message/rfc822 as set in the documentation, but I can't find a way to send also the Thread id.
I tried adding it as a header (example: Thread-Id) to the MimeMessage, but it only works when i send the message to Outlook - there the message is sent to the same thread.
I have also populated the In-Reply-To header, the References header and the Subject is the same as in the original thread with additional 'Re:'. Gmail still creates a new thread for this message.

**Update:**
I have tried using the upload uri with parameter uploadType=multipart and here is my request:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="=-EEoaSdATsa0it8EbymRVdg=="

--=-EEoaSdATsa0it8EbymRVdg==
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

eyJ0aHJlYWRJZCI6IjE1ZTdlZmJhYTc3MzViZjcifQ==

--=-EEoaSdATsa0it8EbymRVdg==
Content-Type: message/rfc822

From: deni.gencheva@gmail.com
Date: Fri, 27 Oct 2017 16:13:37 +0300
Subject: Re: RE:
Message-Id: <ESXEYD0PP2U4.RL2HHWMRGNXE@localhost.localdomain>
Sender: {sender email}
Reply-To: {sender email}
To: {one receiver email}
In-Reply-To: 
 =?us-ascii?q?
=3CHE1PR0402MB3323926A291565E98E66C1DCFC720=40HE1PR0402MB3323=2Eeur?=
 =?us-ascii?q?prd04=2Eprod=2Eoutlook=2Ecom=3E?=
References:<HE1PR0402MB3323926A291565E98E66C1DCFC720@HE1PR0402MB3323.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com>
<CAJM2npmj3DWntngux8KovxPoNJ+KOS4tKm=LAo1YoG3vxWLQdg@mail.gmail.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=-VCM8QFnp+o3VG1fmByraaw=="

--=-VCM8QFnp+o3VG1fmByraaw==
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="test document.rtf"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test document.rtf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Id: <5e655580-14b6-0d1f-9e86-ad1c590691db>

{attachment base64 encoded content}

--=-VCM8QFnp+o3VG1fmByraaw==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=-pst5gHw2fNhIKAdrMRT2wg=="

--=-pst5gHw2fNhIKAdrMRT2wg==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

{message body as plain text}

--=-pst5gHw2fNhIKAdrMRT2wg==
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

{message body as html}

--=-pst5gHw2fNhIKAdrMRT2wg==--

--=-VCM8QFnp+o3VG1fmByraaw==--

--=-EEoaSdATsa0it8EbymRVdg==--
```

But API returns an error which states that multipart/related is not an allowed content type.

Comment: Please include your code ideally https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve